# Execute npm command in child directory from netcore deployment script

Tags: asp.net-core, npm, webpack, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have netcore webAPI project where frontend with package.json and angular CLI is not located in the root folder.
Before deployment, i need to execute `npm` command in the `./ClientApp` folder.

Project structure:

```
├── ClientApp
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── angular.json
│   ├── node_modules
│   └── ...
├── Controllers
├── Views
├── *.csproj
└── startup.cs
```

If packpage.json was in the root folder it could be done in the `*.csproj` file like this:

```
<Exec Command="npm run prod" />
```

However, before executing the following command i need to change directory.
Something like this:

```
  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec Command="cd .\ClientApp; npm run prod" />
```

Is there any working solution in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your csproj file should be like this

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot> // you define the folder to run npm script
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
<!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />

<!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
<ItemGroup>
    <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
    <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
    <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </ResolvedFileToPublish>
</ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

The `$(SpaRoot)` is a value you define in the property group so the build will know the working dir for your angular app